# What UNIQUIE user agent is there to detect a windows 8 device specifically?

Tags: jquery, windows, user-interface

For example:

for ipad or iphone

> function isiPhone(){
>       return (
>           //Detect iPhone
>           (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
>           //Detect iPod
>           (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
>       ); }

for android:

> $(document).ready(function(){   var isAndroid =
>   navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android");   if(isAndroid >
>   -1)   {
>         //It is an Android device. Redirect to Android Version.   }       });​

Comment: what i'm looking for is something to direct to specific code for touch events in windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either of these will work:

```
 var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();


var isTouchPad = deviceAgent.indexOf('touch');
```